Elementary functions such that $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} f(n) \left( \zeta(n)-1 \right)$ can be evaluated, but $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} f(n)$ can't
Background
The general context for this question is the topic of rational zeta series. What I've found so far, is that it usually the case that sums of the form $$\zeta_{f} := \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} f(n) \left( \zeta(n)-1 \right) \label{1}\tag{1} $$ are more difficult to evaluate than sums of the form $$S_{f} := \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} f(n). \label{2}\tag{2} $$
Examples

For instance, if we take $g(n) = \frac{1}{n!}$, then we have $$ S_{g} = \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n!} = e-2, \tag{3}\label{3} $$ but for $ \zeta_{g}$ a closed form is not known.
Also if we consider $h(n) = \frac{1}{n^2}$, then we have $$S_{h} = \frac{\pi^2}{6} -1. \tag{4}\label{4}$$ However, an evaluation of $\zeta_{h}$ appears to be still out of reach.
If we take $v(n) = \frac{(-1)^n}{n-1}$, we have $$ S_{v} = \ln(2), \tag{5}\label{5}$$ but an evaluation of $\zeta_{v}$ seems to be elusive -- see also equation (1.23) in corollary 4 of the following paper.

Question
I wonder whether there are any cases for which the situation is reversed. In other words, I am curious as to whether there are examples of functions such that \eqref{1} can be evaluated, but \eqref{2} cannot. Both $\zeta_{f}$ and $S_{f}$ should be finite, so an example like $q(n) = \frac{1}{n}$ -- where we have $\zeta_{q} = 1-\gamma$, but $S_{q}$ diverges -- does not count. Moreover, the function ought to be elementary on $\mathbb{R}_{\geq 2}$.
Notes

In examples \eqref{3}, \eqref{4}, and \eqref{5}, the sums can be decomposed into $ \zeta_{f} = \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} f(n) \zeta(n)  - S_{f} := \zeta'_{f} - S_{f}$, where $\zeta'_{f}$ can't be evaluated (yet), so $\zeta_{f}$ can't be evaluated either.
We require that $f(\cdot)$ is elementary in order to rule out certain pathological examples. For instance, user Conrad pointed out in the MSE version of this question that $f(x) := \frac{1}{x^{2} \left( \zeta(x)-1\right)} $ could work, but this example is not in the spirit of the question. The same applies to the zero function.
A lemma that is possibly useful and relevant can be found on p. 23 of the following paper (PDF) by Borwein et al. It says that if $f(z) = \sum_{m=2}^{\infty} f_{m} z^{m}$ is analytic on the closed unit disk, we have $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f(1/n) = f(1) + \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} f_{m} \left( \zeta(m)-1 \right).  $$

